# Is it possible to acquire graph data of a specific site using Python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

Is it possible to scrape the graph data of [this site](https://www.jepx.jp/electricpower/market-data/spot/bid_curves.html) using Python's requests or selenium?

I am looking where the original data of the graph is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python libraries such as NetworkX, BeautifulSoup, and Requests to scrape the website and extract the relevant data. For example, you can use Requests to fetch the HTML content of the website, and then use Beautiful Soup to parse the HTML and extract the relevant data points. You can then use NetworkX to create and manipulate the graph data structure.